# Permissions problem with Magento 2.2.0, Nginx, Ubuntu Server only in var/cache/mage-tags

Tags: magento2, nginx, linux

I keep getting the following types of errors:

`Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/opt/magento2ce/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---3d0_TRANSLATE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/magento2ce/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663`

and

`Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /opt/magento2ce/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 512`

Originally I noticed a problem only when applying new themes. After doing more testing, the issue seems to only happen when `bin/magento setup:upgrade` or `bin/magento setup:di:compile` is run. Both are being run as the correct file system owner `appsuser`. And there are no errors in the console output when these commands are run. For reference here is web server user and checking groups from root:

```
# ps aux | grep nginx
root     23987  0.0  0.0  14224   992 pts/0    S+   18:18   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
root     26437  0.0  0.0 125928  1740 ?        Ss   18:01   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 26438  0.0  0.1 126304  5740 ?        S    18:01   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 26439  0.0  0.0 125928  3392 ?        S    18:01   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 26440  0.0  0.1 126460  6060 ?        S    18:01   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 26441  0.0  0.0 125928  3392 ?        S    18:01   0:00 nginx: worker process


# groups appsuser 
appsuser : appsuser www-data
```

The permissions that end up wrong are always in `var/cache/mage-tags/` They have the web server file owner as the user and group owner (`appsuser:appsuser`) when it should be `appsuser:www-data` like the rest of '/opt/magento2ce/` directory. All other files get created with correct user and group.

**Running the following always resolves the issue** (modified from ref "install & configure Magento2" #3 from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html) ):
`chown -R :www-data var/cache/mage-tags/`

I don't understand how all newly generated files in `var/cache/*` except `var/cache/mage-tags/*` end up with the correct permissions. I even have the SGID set with `chmod -R g+s /opt/magento2ce/` and the `/opt/magento2ce/var/cache/mage-tags/*` directory still ends up doing its own thing.

**Does anybody have a permanent fix for this?**

The original setup process i used for install is [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html) and [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html). I modified accordingly because this is hosted on a multi-user system that had an existing web server user and group.

There is a thread that was closed [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12156) with original details.

Similar issue [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187598/magento-2-permissions-problem) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198239/magento-2-permission-denied-with-colinmollenhour-module-cache)

Comment: I have a similar error, but at vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on 663 and 646. The command chown -R :www-data var/cache/mage-tags/ fixed the problem as it did for you.

Comment: You need to (1) sudo usermod -aG www-data appuser (2) restart your system (3) on magento project root folder "find var -type -exec chmod g+w {} \;" (4) on root folder of magento project "find var generated pub/static pub/media -type d -exec chmod g+sw {} \;" I have tested it on the Magento EE 2.3

Comment: @Abbas thank you for your solution, its working